# Dúvida navbar fixa no topo com Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bootstrap-3

Quando adiciono a classe "navbar-fixed-top" ela "come" 50px da página, uso na navbar, links, para divs e sempre que um link é clicado os primeiros 50px ficam embaixo da navbar, oque eu quero fazer é evitar que esses px fiquem embaixo da navbar, quando o link for clicado. 
OBS: já adicionei o padding-top no body, o problema não é com a primeira div logo após a navbar, mas sim com as outras. 
HTML da navbar:

```
<nav id="nav" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#menu" aria-expanded="false">
                <span class="sr-only"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                <img style="margin-top: -10px;" alt="Brand" class="img-responsive" src="">
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="menu">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right text-center">
                <li><a href="#quem-somos" class="scroll link-hover"><b>QUEM SOMOS</b></a></li>
                <li><a href="#contato" class="scroll link-hover"><b>CONTATO</b></a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="link-hover"><b>LOGIN</b></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

HTML da #contato:

```
<div id="contato" class="bg-color text-white">
  <div class="container padding-divisors">
    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 margin-bottom-titles">
      <h2 class="text-center">RECEBA MAIS INFORMAÇÕES</h2>
    </div>
    <form method="post" action="#">
      <div id="form-contato" class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="nome">Seu nome (obrigatótio)</label>
          <input required id="nome" name="nome" type="text" class="form-control">
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Css:

```
body{
    background-color: whitesmoke !important;
    padding-top: 50px !important;
}
#nav{
    box-shadow: black 0 0 5px;
    opacity: 0.3;
}
```

Ex:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Aqui uma parte do padding-top da div#contato está embaixo da navbar, minha dúvida é como evitar isso. 
Agradeço a ajuda!

Comment: Coloque seu CSS, pelo menos a parte do topo.

Comment: tenta tirar o padding, usa um reset antes de adicionar o bootstrap :3

Comment: Caso ele não funcione, apenas colocando seu próprio CSS como o @Diego comentou

Comment: Coloca o html desse trecho

Answer (score 1):

Eu faria assim :

```
body{
    background-color: whitesmoke !important;
    padding: 0px !important;
}
#nav{
    background-color: whitesmoke !important;
    box-shadow: black 0 0 5px;
    opacity: 0.3;
}
```

Comment: O Bootstrap recomenda que quando a classe "navbar-fixed-top" for utilizada que use padding de no mínimo 50px. Sua solução não resolve, é meio complicado de explicar essa minha dúvida, mas quero que quando a algum link seja clicado (os link apontam para divs na mesma página) a navbar não fique por cima do conteúdo da div, como acontece na imagem de exemplo, talvez com javascript dê pra resolver esse problema, mas não tenho ideia de como fazer. @MagicHat

Comment: coloca o html do trecho

Comment: html adicionado @MagicHat